# Selenium tests failing for React components

Tags: reactjs, selenium

The app has legacy code that isn't React, it is being ported to React as I write this. Code had/has Selenium tests that are/were using globals such as `document.readyState` etc. That doesn't really work with React as the components are mounted and `readyState` is complete without the render getting done; this in turn fails the tests on Selenium as it can't find the target elements sometimes if the render takes a while.

I have tried to look for other posts but only found solutions that have some sort of `setTimeout` based solution. But that isn't really the best imo so I am looking for any other approach to solve this that doesn't hopefully require a global var.

Comment: webdriverwaits were designed for this sort of thing.  You won't need to monitor readyState at all.  (and it's very unreliable to do that for anything other than a traditional page load which Selenium already does...)  There are situations where placeholder DOM items are populated first, which can cause some issues.  When they are being updated readyState will change, but it's very difficult to sort of jump in there at the right time to monitor that.  Can you give a specific example where you're having trouble?

Comment: The UI is as follows:

There are two sidebars/columns with each having ctas of their own; when the user selects options from each sidebar a list is rendered is the third on rest of the page as the third column as a table. The table has header that is rendered quickly as it doesn't depend on api calls. Selenium test for testing whether the table has rendered is failing as it finds the DOM  and the table header but not the list.

Comment: And its not like it fails everywhere, we observed that it fails at times on the pages which involves lists and or when they take time to load.

Comment: yeah, the readystate check will be unreliable... you'll need to test for specific expected content.

Comment: We are checking for specific components, it's the waiting for api calls that makes it to fail, and that too only sometimes. Components have test ids that tests look for specifically.

Comment: One thing that may help is to catch "Stale Element" exceptions.  These are great for letting you know when the DOM is still being updated.  They will be thrown if a call is made on a webelement who's reference has changed due to the DOM being updated... if caught, you know the DOM is not "ready" yet, so get the element again.  (Function-ize the call and try/catch... if exception caught is stale element, re-call function.)